No Output When Running get_tags File with Boto3, Lambda, and Amazon Rekognition
I’m working on a project using the AWS SDK for Python (Boto3). My setup involves uploading an image to an S3 bucket, which triggers a Lambda function. This Lambda function is supposed to use Amazon Rekognition to scan the image and return tags. However, when I run my get_tags file, I get no output and no error messages. Here are the details:
Here is my 'get_object_tagging' code snippet:
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
try:
    response = s3.get_object_tagging(
        Bucket='your-bucket-name',  # Input your actual bucket name
        Key='images/cat.jpg'
    )
    tag_values = [tag['Value'] for tag in response['TagSet']]
    output = ', '.join(tag_values)
    print(output)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


Did you check that the image actually has tags added to it? It looks like the problem is with your function that should do the tagging.
